# Title and description aren't shown using generateMetadata()

Tags: next.js

I have dynamic pages and I need to add dynamic metadata there, but for some reasons metadata was not added. (I duplicated the code just to test if metadata works)

```
import { use } from 'react'
import Phrase from '../../../../components/Phrase'

async function getPhrase(id) {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URI}/api/phrases/2/${id}`)
  const data = await res.json()
  return data
} 

//This method I'm using to generate metadata

export async function generateMetadata({ params }) { 
  const id = params.id
  let data = use(getPhrase(id))

  return {
    title: data[0].title,
    description: `Level ${data[0].title}`,
  }
}

export default function page({ params }) {
  const id = params.id
  let data = use(getPhrase(id))

  return (
    <div className="p-10 ">
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center px-5">
        <Score col_id={data[0].id} />

        {data[0].phrases.map((i, index) => {
          return <Phrase key={index} phrases={i} />
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, please check what you are fetching here:
you may pass wrong data in return block :

```
const id = params.id
let data = use(getPhrase(id));
console.log("Meta",data)
```